# Bootstrap on mobile device not firing

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have no idea, why this form is not working on mobile. When I run it on Chrome, Edge, FF (all latest) - it proceeds to the next section. Only one field required for now - WIP.
I put it into this fiddle, and can't seem to find the issue. Desktop - no issues. The validation kicks in, proceeds. Mobile, nope.
Does anyone have any idea (except for cleaning up the code, which I still need to do - work in progress)

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Forgot the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dnq1uvk0/1/

Comment: We don't need a fiddle. We need you to put a [mcve] in your question. Use the snippet button in the editor to do the same thing that you can do on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was found. I was referencing to the jquery.validate-file, calling it using "http". On the desktop this was no problem, yet the mobile browser did not like that. Changed it to use "https", since I am calling the page over https, too, did the trick.
Closing this question.